# Does a constant term in a nonstationary AR model always imply a trend?

Tags: stationarity, autoregressive, trend, unit-root

Given an $AR(k)$ model of the form $$y_t = \alpha_1y_{t-1}+...+\alpha_ky_{t-k} + \mu + \varepsilon_t$$
with $\alpha$ satisfying $(1-\alpha_1 z - ... -\alpha_k z^k ) = 0$ for $z=1$, does a nonzero $\mu$ necessarily imply that the series follows a linear trend?

If  one solution to the aforemetioned equation is $1$, is it therefore always true that an $AR$ process written as $$y_t = t +\alpha_1y_{t-1}+...+\alpha_ky_{t-k} + \varepsilon_t$$ is $I(2)$?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: How do you derive I(2) from a linear trend + a single unit root?

Comment: @RichardHardy To be honest, I only derived it for a random walk. A process written as: $y_t = t + y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$, when differences are taken, becomes a trend-stationary process, namely $\Delta y_t = t + \varepsilon_t$ which still has to be differenced once to become stationary. Therefore, I conclude that the sum of a random walk and a linear trend is I(2). Am I wrong?
Thanks for your comment

Comment: No, a process that does not contain a unit root need not be differenced to become stationary. Doing that would be a mistake known as *overdifferencing*. You may [search this keyword](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=overdifferencing) to learn more. And no, this does not make the process I(2). It is I(1) with a linear trend.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for your answer. However, I have just noticed I misspecified the above question - it is obvious that a random walk with drift features a linear trend and it is only $I(1)$, excuse me for the confusion of my question. Still, despite the $y_t = t + y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$ process has a quadratic trend, should I consider it $I(1)$ and consider any ts process $I(0)$?

Comment: Treat deterministic trends separately from stochastic trends (unit roots). An I(1) is an I(1) regardless of whether it has a deterministic trend or not.